# String Separation at Space using python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am stuck at a place, where i have to extract a variable between two spaces in python. I am completely new to python. 
I have a data string as below:
Data: 1 Hello:Coordinator
Please give me a code, by which i can get "1" out of this string.
Please help.

```
list_number=[]
value= "Data: 1 Hello:Coordinator"
list_number= value.split(" ")

print(list_number[1])
```

Comment: The value variable in your code isn't the same as the one you have in your question.

Comment: I am totally new to programming. Asking a basic question. The String value is stored in variable value. When i am splitting it, i am trying to store it in a list, which is list_number and i am accessing the data from 1st index in the list.

Comment: Change value from `"Data: Hello:Coordinator"` to `"Data: 1 Hello:Coordinator"` which is the data string you have.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary what is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry for posting Wrong question. It was TOO Easy. I was doing Small Mistake. SORRY once again. I was doing careless Mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner, you should look more carefully at your code. Take it slow. Go character by character. You are missing the character "1" in your string.

```
value = "Data: 1 Hello:Coordinator"
```